# Syntax or way to perform INSERT INTO TABLE (cols) SELECT col1+','+col2+','+col3 from __new

Tags: sql, triggers, sybase, database-replication

I have a lot of code and function riding on the ability to insert OLD and NEW values BEFORE a trigger INSERT UPDATE and DELETE, in Sybase ADS and Postgresql. I am making this to make triggered replication that can capture and run each IUD statement as it comes, but many tables don't have primary keys so I have to capture all OLD values for UPDATES and DELETES and NEW values for INSERTS and UPDATES. Either that or I create temp tables for any table that replicates.

I have to make it dynamic or where columns can be queried or stored as a set of delimited columns in a table, because a set of users will change them at random times. I appreciate any help of advice offered.

The following code seems to give invlaid operand errors but I don't know if I am further off than I think.

```
--1. using "temp tables" per replicating source
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'table' AND type = 'U')
THEN
(select * into #table_repllog from __new;
Alter table #table_repllog add column Repl_TriggerCmd char(10);
Alter table #table_repllog add column Repl_Status Char(50);
Alter table #table_repllog add column Repl_TimeDate timestamp;
update #table_repllog set Repl_TriggerType='I',Repl_Status='READY',Repl_CreateTimeDate=NOW() WHERE Repl_TriggerType IS NULL,Repl_Status IS NULL,Repl_CreateTimeDate IS NULL)


--OR

--2. INSERT multiple delimited values into NewValues column

INSERT INTO log (TableName, TriggerCmd, Status, TimeDate,NewValues) select 'tablename','INSERT','READY', NOW(),col1+','+col2+','+col3 from __new;
```

2. is the most desired outcome, but #1 is probably healthier and less tricky from a DB persepctive. Essentially, if I can find a way to store multiple NEW or OLD values in a column (#2) that will allow multiple tables to write to it so I won't have to have 1 table per replicating source like #1.

I appreciate anyone who can give a pointer or advice on the code. The sample is for an INSERT for SYBASE, which I will pass on to UPDATE and DELETE trigger statement. I mentioned Postgresql but I will make a separate but equivalent question.

Thanks.

Comment: I removed the Postgres tag because the code is clearly not Postgresql, and likely Sybase.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I started with a question for both but I don't want to be to greedy, but wanted to explain my intent with the back story. I will create a separate question for postgresql.